# How to use Power BI Azure Maps Visual?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, azure-maps, microsoft365

We want to use Azure maps in place of the old bing maps in our Power Bi  reports. Azure maps for Power BI is currently disabled in our organization. If we enable it in our organization, will it start incurring charges? If yes, how much are the charges and how will we be able to limit the charges?

We aim to use it in our Power BI Pro workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure Maps visual in Power BI is part of Power BI and has no additional costs. In the future there may be additional features that could be enabled that may have charges related to them, but you would likely have to opt into these and those costs would be clearly documented. Documentation on the Azure Maps visual can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/power-bi-visual-get-started

Answer (score 1):

No. You will not start incurring charges after enabling Azure Maps Power BI. This is because the [Azure Maps](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/azure/azure-maps) visual in Power BI is part of the other visualizations included in your Power BI pro subscription.

You will, therefore, be able to publish and share reports with other users. Since you have a Power BI Pro subscription, each report viewer must, therefore, have a Power BI Pro license to view the shared report.

At the time of answering this question, Power BI Pro costs $10 per month for each user. Therefore, the price will be influenced by the number of users you share the reports with.

As for limiting charges, if your organization is large, you may need higher refresh rates per day and larger model size limits for your visualizations. To limit your charges, you may choose the Power BI Premium Capacity option, which does not require per-user licenses.

The Power BI Premium Capacity pricing starts at $4,995/capacity/month. Please note that this option requires a Power BI Pro license to publish content into Power BI Premium Capacity.

Other factors to consider could be the complexity and frequency of your Power BI reports, as you might find cheaper alternatives within the [different price structures](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/) based on these needs.